# How to break while condition when its true?

Tags: python

How to break the while loop, when the condition is true?

I tried using break under an if statement, but it's not working.

```py
def proallocate():
    while True:    
        conn = sqlite3.connect('database.db')
        cur = conn.cursor()
        pid = cur.execute("SELECT project_id FROM Upload WHERE status= ?", ("NULL",))
        for pd in pid:
            a = str(pd)
            projectid = re.sub('[\(\),\{\}<>]', '', a)
            url = "https://picture-us.amazon.com/colorauthor/view/"+projectid+""
            print(url)
            req = requests.Session()
            resp = req.get(url, auth=HTTPKerberosAuth(mutual_authentication=False), verify="./amazon_dev_certs.pem")
            soup = BeautifulSoup(resp.text, 'html.parser')
            project_status_latest = soup.find_all('tr')[-1].get_text()
            if ("Project Ready" in project_status_latest):
                proid[0] = projectid
                print(proid[0])

            else:
                cur.execute("UPDATE Upload SET status = ? WHERE project_id = ?", ("Reserved", projectid))
                conn.commit()
```

I expect that the loop should stop when the if condition passes.

Comment: Any `break` will break the `for` loop only. But you can `return` from the function.

Comment: There's no `break` in the code you shared. Please share your actual attempt, and indicate what exactly was the issue with it (i.e., actual outcome vs desired outcome)

Comment: i have used break under if statement, but i doesn't work @Mureinik

Comment: @KlausD. where to add return ?

Comment: Well, from where do you want to `return`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

here is a simplified version of what you could do:

```
condition = True
while condition:
    for i in range(10):
        print(i)
        if i == 3:
            condition = False
            break
```

`break` will break the `for` loop and setting `condition = False` will cause the `while` loop to stop.

and are you sure you want to `conn = sqlite3.connect('database.db')` in your `while` loop?

Comment: The while loop is the first line within a function so the OP may as well just `return`

Comment: @Sayse there is a connection that still needs to be closed. returning may be a bit harsh... (the connection should be within a `with` context anyway....) but yeah, `return` works.

Comment: @hiroprotagonist it worked ! thanks, when i run the function it keeps on running, how  to exit from it?

Answer (score 0):

```
    q = True
    while q:    
        conn = sqlite3.connect('database.db')
        cur = conn.cursor()
        pid = cur.execute("SELECT project_id FROM Upload WHERE status= ?", ("NULL",))
        for pd in pid:
            a = str(pd)
            projectid = re.sub('[\(\),\{\}<>]', '', a)
            url = "https://picture-us.amazon.com/colorauthor/view/"+projectid+""
            print(url)
            req = requests.Session()
            resp = req.get(url, auth=HTTPKerberosAuth(mutual_authentication=False), verify="./amazon_dev_certs.pem")
            soup = BeautifulSoup(resp.text, 'html.parser')
            project_status_latest = soup.find_all('tr')[-1].get_text()
            if ("Project Ready" in project_status_latest):
                proid[0] = projectid
                q = False
                break
            else:
                cur.execute("UPDATE Upload SET status = ? WHERE project_id = ?", ("Reserved", projectid))
                conn.commit()
                break


it worked
```